# how to specify variable order using ggcoef_compare?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm working with `ggcoef_compare` to plot coefficients from two separate models. I want to specify the variable order.

The issue: my code worked in August, but it no longer specifies the correct variable order today. I've updated all the necessary packages (`ggplot2`, `GGally`), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

It's hard to provide a reproduce example of my code because I'm working with spatial models, but here is the code for my plot:

```
models <- list("OLS" = ols, "Spatial Error" = err)

ggcoef_compare(models, 
               variable_labels = c(
                 localtaxrate = "Local Tax Rate",
                 unemprate = "Unemployment Rate",
                 gini_mean = "Gini",
                 theil_race = "Racial Segregation",
                 pctblack = "Percent Black",
                 `log(pop)` = "Population (log)"),
               facet_labeller = label_wrap_gen(15),
               conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95, 
               significance = NULL)
```

When I run this code, the plot displays variables in alphabetical order: Gini, Local Tax Rate, Population, Percent Black, Racial Segregation, Unemployment Rate. I should also note that when I run my models (`ols` and `err`), I order the variables the same way I list them in my code for `ggcoef_compare`.